# Extract Portion of the URL after "Home"

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I need to extract the rest of the portion of the URL after "home"

for example the URLs can be

```
https://www.example.com/site/country/home/products
https://www.example.com/site/country/home/products/consumer
https://www.example.com/site/country/home/products/consumer/kids
```

The keywords in the url "site", "country" might change.

All I need in the output is:

```
 /products 
 /products/consumer 
 /products/consumer/kids
```

I tried using Regex, but didn't worked in above situation

Comment: Find the first index of "/home/" and take the substring after that?

Comment: What regex did you try? Also, why not just use [String.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: [Something like this should work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oy2M22) `string rest = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("/products"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `System.Uri` class to extract the segments of the URL:

```
Uri link = new Uri("https://www.example.com/site/country/home/products/consumer/kids");
string[] segs = link.Segments;

int idxOfHome = Array.IndexOf(segs, "home/");

string restOfUrl = string.Join("", segs, idxOfHome+1, segs.Length  - (idxOfHome + 1));
```

Yeilds:

> products/consumer/kids

Comment: The problem with segments is, if I have a space in the url it returns the encoded form. In my case for **/products/consumer/for men** it was returning **/products/consumer/for%40men** then I just used Trim and IndexOf.

Comment: You could URL decode it, but that's not a space it's@

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Corion and David in the comments, in this case, the simplest method is probably just to find the index of `/home/` and then strip everything up to that point (but not second `/`):

```
string home = "/home/";
int homeIndex = url.IndexOf(home);
string relativeUrl = url.Substring(homeIndex + home.Length - 1);
```

Using a regular expression, you want to match the `/home/` substring, and capture the second `/` and everything following it:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"/home(/.*)");
string relativeUrl = "/";
if (match.Success) {
    relativeUrl = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: @SitecoreSXADeveloper I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

its a so simple c# code i think it may help you

```
string sub = "https://www.example.com/site/country/home/products";
        string temp = "";
        string[] ss = sub.Split('/');
        for(int i = 0; i < sub.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ss[i] == "home")
            {
                i++;
                for (int j = i; j < ss.Length; j++)
                    temp +='/'+ ss[j];

                break;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Comment: Although it's more general than most answers here, there is no need to split and loop; just find the index of `home` and take the substring.

Comment: i only give an idea and i think indexof get only character and indexofany get array of characters but may be not sequenced

Comment: It's not really a bad idea, but the code is a lot more work than is needed, and this approach is better using Crowcoder's answer with `System.Uri`. Additionally, you should check `ss.Length` instead of `sub.Length` in the `for` loop. `string.IndexOf` will find the starting index of a substring in the string, so it works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy using Regex. Please use the following Regex and test your scenario. It works fine.

Regex: `'(?<=\/home).*\b'`

No need to worry about front portion before home. As soon as it finds home, it will take words after home.